# can build include all resource files in main module instead of separate resource dlls

Tags: c#, dll, embedded-resource

We use Visual Studio 2008 to build numerous C# applications. These applications are localized. The default locale is english and the other is spanish. The build produces the main EXE/DLL with the default resources embedded in it and another resource.dll for the spanish resources. Is it possible to somehow change how visual studio creates these resource dlls so the spanish resources are also included in the main module and not a separate resource dll? If so, how?  My goal here is avoid having to change our automated build process and our installs while using the built-in support for resource files in the IDE.

Comment: Changing this shouldn't "simplify" a build process, which should be automated anyway it is done.

Comment: Our build process is automated. But it and our installs need to be changed to support these resource dlls if we cannot embed them.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own localization and you will not need external .dll-s. In my opinion, the built-in localization feature of .Net/VS is very bad and I always use custom solution(s) like text file(s) with messages in different languages. It is easy to give it to translator and put back the result.